# Passing UI objects as Constructor Parameters

Tags: android, memory

`public ContactsPanel(Activity activity,GoogleMap mGoogleMap)`

I have a Class with this Constructor. This class basically inflates a `UI` on "activity" with Marker details when a marker is clicked on `mGoogleMaps`. My questions for the community are:

1. If I am creating 1st instance of `ContactsPanel` then am I forcing OS to duplicate memory allocation for the objects activity and `mGoogleMap`?
2. And what if I have 10 instances of `ContactsPanel`? Will that mean 10 Google Maps in memory and 10 Activities in memory? Or will all the objects will be referring to same object, that was originally created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't be duplicating instances of `activity` or `googleMaps` or any other `Ojects` which you pass as parameter.

Once you create instance, it will be stored in heap at memory location X, when you invoke `ContactPanel(activity,mGoogleMap)` then a new instance of `ContactsPanel` is created at location Y in heap and the variables `activity` and `mGoogleMaps` inside `ContactPanel` are still pointing to X in heap.

**EDIT**

To answer your question about drawbacks, It's **OK** if you have `N` modifiers for single instance of heavy `object` however the problem comes in memory leak,
Consider you shared your `activity` instance with 10 objects, now even if you finished your `activity` , but one of your 10 objects which holds reference to that is still live in memory, it wont let `gc` to collect activity's memory.

Comment: And 10 instances of ContactPanel basically would mean 10 different "handlers" or "references" to manipulate the original mGoogleMap. Are there any drawbacks that you can possibly sight in regards of having multiple "handlers" for a complex object like GoogleMap or Activity in contrast to having only one "Static" reference exposed from root Activity/Fragment that originally hosts it?

Comment: MapFragment is the root Fragment that originally hosts mGoogleMap. ContactPanel is also instantiated from this fragment. 

In my constructor for ContactsPanel, I have a static int objCount that I increment and log in the constructor. 

I use ContactsPanel to inflate UI with details of different POIs on map and the objCount remains at one after multiple UI inflates using ContactPanel Object for different POIs. 

However, when I switch from MapFragment to another fragment and then back to MapFragment, each time the objCount for ContactPanel is incremented.

Comment: So after 10 movements from MapFragment and back to MapFragment, my objCount is 10, does this mean I have 10 instances of ContactPanel?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass activity and map in your constructor it will just pass the reference, it will not going to duplicate any of the object.

So you can say all the object reference to same object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you use `WeakReference<>` to get instance of `Activity` or `Object` and to work with

```
 class ExampleWeakReference {
    private WeakReference<DashboardActivity> mActivityWeakReference;

    ExampleWeakReference(DashboardActivity activity) {
        mActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<DashboardActivity>(activity);
    }

    private void doSomethingWithId() {
        DashboardActivity dashboardActivity = mActivityWeakReference.get();
        dashboardActivity.mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```